# Keep constant value for label in custom cell when the view reloaded, change value when action occurs second time change label value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, custom-cell

This question may be asked different manner but my condition is another way so before setting duplicate check this. From root view i am calling right view, right view have some options when i press one row the custom cell label value should change to some other value i had done it. But when i call root view and call right view again the label value goes to original value so how to keep same value for custom cell label value when view reload it??

initially am assigning value for label is

```
(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row==0)
        {
            cell.rightpanelLabel1.text=@"Switch to Photo View";
        } 
}
```

then when cell press happened i changed label value like this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell=[[ViewProfileRightPanelCell alloc]init];
     static NSString *cellidentifier=@"ViewProfileRightPanelCell";
    cell=(ViewProfileRightPanelCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    for (cell in [ViewProfileRightPanelTableView subviews])
    {
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[ViewProfileRightPanelCell class]])
        {
            if (cell.tag == indexPath.row)
            {

                if ([cell.rightpanelLabel1.text isEqualToString:@"Switch to Photo View"] )
                {
                    cell.rightpanelLabel1.text=@"Switch to List View";
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to keep the same value even when the view reloaded again but another condition is if i press again cell it should change to previous value and am using custom cell

Answer (score 0):

You're on a good track - you have custom cell which helps a lot.

Make another properties to your custom cell:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* selectedText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* deselectedText;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL selected;
```

when you create cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath: initialize both texts:

```
if(indexPath.row==0)
{
    cell.selectedText= @"Switch to Photo View";
    cell.deselectedText = @"Switch to List View";
    cell.selected = NO;
}
```

And:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell=[[ViewProfileRightPanelCell alloc]init];
     static NSString *cellidentifier=@"ViewProfileRightPanelCell";
    cell=(ViewProfileRightPanelCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    for (cell in [ViewProfileRightPanelTableView subviews])
    {
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[ViewProfileRightPanelCell class]])
        {
            if (cell.tag == indexPath.row)
            {
                cell.selected = !cell.selected;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.selected = NO;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And on your custom cell make custom setter for "selected" property

```
- (void) setSelected:(BOOL) selected
{
     _selected = selected;
     if(selected)
    {
         self.rightpanelLabel1.text = self.selectedText;
    }
    else
    {
         self.rightpanelLabel1.text = self.deselectedText;
    }
}
```

Comment: k i will try this once over i will inform you but doubt when loading the initial value of label should switch to photo view

Comment: What you mean ? What's the problem with that.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assingn) BOOL selected;  this line shows warning  when i ran the app it is crashing

Comment: Oh sorry I never compiled that code. "assign" - there was missspelling - I was just trying to show you an idea - not really make code to solve your problem in 100%